# How to write a trigger for a table based on the value of a column in another table?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, mysql-workbench, database-trigger

I have a table "A" with a column "flag" as below:

```
candidate_id | name | flag 
-----------------------------
0001         |  ABC |  f  | 
0002         |  DEF |  t  | 
0003         |  GHI |  t  |
```

and a table "B" with a column "status" as below:

```
candidate_id | status 
-----------------------------
0001         |  Applied  |
0002         |  Applied  |
0003         |  Applied  |
```

I want to write a trigger with the following logic:

- When an entry happens in table "B", I want to change the "status" value to 'Rejected' only if the last inserted "candidate_id" in table "B", which refers "candidate_id" in table "A", has a "flag=t".

I've written a trigger as follows, but I'm not able to find the syntax in MySql to fetch the value of "flag" for a particular candidate_id:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_status_to_rejected
Before INSERT ON db.B FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
    DECLARE candidate_id INTEGER;
    candidate_id = NEW.candidate_id;
    // Im stuck from here with the MySQL syntax
    get the last_inserted candidate_id,
    check in table A whether this candidate_id flag=='t'
    then:
        set NEW.status = 'Rejected'
```

Can you please guide me here? I've searched many solutions but not able to find when another table needs to be checked for a value. I would also want to know how to insert a new row with status='Rejected', instead of updating the last inserted row. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I tested:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_status_to_rejected
Before INSERT ON B FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        DECLARE _flag CHAR(1);
        SELECT flag INTO _flag FROM A WHERE candidate_id = NEW.candidate_id;
        IF _flag = 't' THEN
                SET NEW.status = 'Rejected';
        ELSE    
                SET NEW.status = 'Applied';
        END IF; 
END
```

Test:

```
mysql> insert into B set candidate_id = '0001';
mysql> insert into B set candidate_id = '0002';
mysql> insert into B set candidate_id = '0003';
```

Result:

```
mysql> select * from B;
+--------------+----------+
| candidate_id | status   |
+--------------+----------+
| 0001         | Applied  |
| 0002         | Rejected |
| 0003         | Rejected |
+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks @bill. That was really helpfull. But workbench throws me errors like:                                1. CHAR(1) - unexpected end of input found, expecting: ';'                                                          2. "IF" is no valid input at this position , expecting: EOF,BACKUP,BEGIN,CACHE...                                                                                               3. "END" is no valid input at this position, expecting: EOF,BACKUP,BEGIN,CACHE... Is there any syntax that we need to update? I'm stuck here after seeing multiple solutions.

Comment: I have no idea what you typed or which window in Workbench you're doing it in. Here's a video about how to create triggers in Workbench: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8o0gETy-OQ All I can say is that I tested the above code, but I used the mysql client, not Workbench. Also I needed to use DELIMITER, like I would when defining any stored procedure, function, or trigger. If you use the proper window for creating triggers in Workbench, you don't need to change the delimiter.